# PircBotX - Transfer String to User

Tags: java

Kind of baffled by this. Recently transferred over to [PircBotX](https://code.google.com/p/pircbotx/) - coding a bot, etc. I have a command that basically requires you give a nick and it will grab the hostname. The nick is a `String`, but PircBotX requires it to be a `User`. Any idea how I'd switch a `String` to a `User` so I can then grab the hostmask?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> PircBotX class has a getUser() method.
>
> How long did you try to search yourself?

I see that the newest version does not have this method, I'm sorry.

In the 2.0.1 version you need

```
User u = getUserChannelDao().getUser(String_here);
```

Comment: When I posted this comment my page refreshed almost instantly (maximum 2 seconds) and then I had the first downvote... Is this some sort of automated system? Or, if someone actually read the post in 1½ seconds flat and decided it was worth a downvote, could you please explain why?